# How can I go through txt-file lines and delete duplicate identifier lines

Tags: powershell, foreach

I have a txt file with this CSV-like format:

```
1234;4312;Name Name;;;;
142;4472;Name Name;;;;
1234;4477;Name Name;;;;
1332;4437;Name Name;;;;
1334;4127;Name Name;;;;
```

Where some duplicates have snuck in. And by duplicates I mean the first field is unique can be one to four numbers. Is there a way to remove the duplicates (The first occurence is the correct one but I'm ok with either) through powershell? Since the lines are not unique I can't use `Sort-Object -Unique`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could still do this with [Sort-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113403) `-unique`. Just crop the first colum and use it for the unique condition:

```
$content = Get-Content 'Your_file_path'
$content | Sort-Object -Unique { ($_ -split ';')[0] }
$content = Set-Content 'Your_file_path'
```

Output of the file:

```
1234;4312;Name Name;;;;
1332;4437;Name Name;;;;
1334;4127;Name Name;;;;
142;4472;Name Name;;;;
```